# Binding php variable to pdo query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So far I have my database records searchable and paginated. I'm having trouble integrating separate sort functions setup by links parameters. ex. `?sort=id, ?sort=last_name etc..`. I can capture the parameter with `isset($_GET['sort']`, but am having trouble binding the variable into my query.

Here is my code

```
$pdo_conn = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name', $database_username, $database_password );

$search_keyword = '';
if(!empty($_POST['search']['keyword'])) {
    $search_keyword = $_POST['search']['keyword'];
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM submissions WHERE company_name LIKE :keyword OR attorney_last_name LIKE :keyword OR attorney_first_name LIKE :keyword ORDER BY id ASC ';  
/* Pagination Code starts */
$per_page_html = '';
$page = 1;
$start=0;
if(!empty($_POST["page"])) {
    $page = $_POST["page"];
    $start=($page-1) * ROW_PER_PAGE;
}
$limit=" limit " . $start . "," . ROW_PER_PAGE;
$pagination_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
$pagination_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pagination_statement->execute();
$row_count = $pagination_statement->rowCount();
if(!empty($row_count)){
    $per_page_html .= "<div style='text-align:center;margin:20px 0px;'>";
    $page_count=ceil($row_count/ROW_PER_PAGE);
    if($page_count>1) {
        for($i=1;$i<=$page_count;$i++){
            if($i==$page){
                $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page current" />';
            } else {
                $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page" />';
            }
        }
    }
    $per_page_html .= "</div>";
}   
$query = $sql.$limit;
$pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
$pdo_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdo_statement->execute();
$result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Ideally, hoping to be able to bind the variable in my query... :sort - 'SELECT * FROM submissions WHERE company_name LIKE :keyword OR attorney_last_name LIKE :keyword OR attorney_first_name LIKE :keyword ORDER BY :sort ASC ';

Comment: You can not bind the variable to :sort, because `ORDER BY xxx` is a part of SQL, not a parameter of the SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : null;

//to prevent SQL injection
if(!in_array($sort, array('id', 'last_name'))) $sort = null;

//use default field to sort
if(!$sort) $sort = 'id';

//build the SQL
$sql = "SELECT * FROM submissions 
        WHERE company_name LIKE :keyword 
             OR attorney_last_name LIKE :keyword 
             OR attorney_first_name LIKE :keyword 
        ORDER BY `$sort` ASC
       ";
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried this, but the query yielded no results with or without the url parameter. ?sort=company_name . I tried removing the ` `'s, but still no results. At first the additional code was throwing an error for this line. if(!in_array($sort, array('id', 'last_name')) $sort = null; , I added another closing parentheses if(!in_array($sort, array('id', 'last_name'))) $sort = null;

Comment: I'm on to something. I'm not sure this is good practice, but it's working. ORDER BY '.$sort.' ASC - it pulls the variable directly into the query.

Comment: the code is only a sample to show how to deal with this problem. the back-quote in `ORDER BY $sort` is used to make sure even if the field name is a keyword the query still works. also, make sure you are using double-quote to construct the sql. if you write single-quote 'ORDER BY $sort', it won't work because in PHP the single-quote doesn't replace the variable.